# Load self hosted fonts not working

Tags: fonts

due to the European GDPR Regulation I need to stop my theme loading fonts from Google and instead load them locally. I've downloaded all Fonts and placed the files in a fonts Directory. I added a @fontface rule in my CSS. (Please take a look below):

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-display: swap;
    src: url('../fonts/roboto-v30-latin-100.eot');
    /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local('Roboto'),
        url('../fonts/roboto-v30-latin-100.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        /* IE6-IE8 */
        url('../fonts/roboto-v30-latin-100.woff2') format('woff2'),
        /* Super Modern Browsers */
        url('../fonts/roboto-v30-latin-100.woff') format('woff'),
        /* Modern Browsers */
        url('../fonts/roboto-v30-latin-100.ttf') format('truetype'),
        /* Safari, Android, iOS */
        url('../fonts/roboto-v30-latin-100.svg#Roboto') format('svg');
    /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

(I repeated this with all font-sizes)

Problem: The local fonts are not loaded. Is it because messed sth. up in the functions.php? I commented out certain parts in the functino.php. Please see below. Do I have to modify this in a certain way?

```php
// 25.10.22
        
        // if(!isset($site_font['url'])){
        //  wp_enqueue_style("sth_GoogleFont","https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,100,200,300,500,600,700,800,900" , false, "1.0");       
        // }
        // else{
        //  $site_font_url = preg_replace("/^http:/i", "https:",$site_font['url']);
        //  wp_enqueue_style("sth_GoogleFont",$site_font_url , false, "1.0");
        // }
```

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time when I have an issue with @font-face is because my src path isn't right. Maybe check the console to see if the call to your fonts files return a 404.

If your font-face is being called in the style.css in the root of your theme then your font path is more likely to be as follow:

```
url('./fonts/roboto-v30-latin-100.woff2') format('woff2')
```

`../` means you go one back to the parent folder where `./` will look at the folder /fonts in your theme folder

@font-face being a css rule I don't think the function you commented out would have anything to do with the fonts not loading.